# Exercise on differentiable function

Tags: analysis, derivatives

$f\colon \mathbb{R} \rightarrow \mathbb{R}$ a differentiable function and $m \in \mathbb{R}$ for which $f'(x)\ge m$ for every $x \in \mathbb{R}$.

Let $Z= \{x\in \mathbb{R} \mid e^{\sin(x)} = f(x)\}$

Proof that:

1) if $m>0$ then $Z \neq\emptyset$

2) if $m>3$ then there's only an element in $Z$

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1) This is because $f$ is strictly increasing but $e^{\sin x}$ is periodic, and both are continuous.

2) This is because $(e^{\sin x})' = e^{\sin x} \cos x \leq e \cdot 1 < 3$, so that  after the first intersection point, the graph of $f$ will always lie above the graph of $e^{\sin x}$.

Answer (score 0):

**Hint**

> (1)From $f'(x)\geq{m}>0$, we get
>   \begin{cases}
> f(x)\geq mx+f(0),&x>0\\
> f(x)\leq -mx+f(0),&x<0
> \end{cases}
>   Then $f$ without upper and lower bounds, but $e^{\sin(x)}$ is bounded. So there are $x_1,x_2$, which satisfy 
>   \begin{cases}
> e^{\sin(x_1)}-f(x_1)<0\\
> e^{\sin(x_2)}-f(x_2)>0
> \end{cases}
>   So where must a zero point $x_0$: $$e^{\sin(x_0)}-f(x_0)=0$$
>
> (2)From $$(e^{\sin(x)}-f(x))'=e^{\sin(x)}\sin x\cos x-f'\leq e-m<0$$ 
>   we can get $e^{\sin(x)}-f(x)$ is decreasing. So it only has one zero point.